# Обработка исключения в асинхронном коде

Tags: python, asyncio

```
import asyncio


async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(7):
        await queue.put(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('Producer Queue size:', queue.qsize())


async def consumer(queue):
    try:
        while True:
            item = await queue.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            print(item)

            if item is None:
                print('Queue is empty')
                queue.task_done()
                break

            if item == 3:
                raise TypeError("Producer got exception")

            queue.task_done()
            print('Queue size:', queue.qsize())

    except TypeError as e:
        print(f'Error happened asf {e}')
        queue.task_done()
        raise e


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    # Запуск продюсера
    await asyncio.gather(producer_task)
    await queue.put(None)
    # .join чтобы работало пока очередь непуста
    await queue.join()
    consumer_task.cancel() # Выход из цикла while
    # Запуск consumer_task с возвратом ошибок
    result = await asyncio.gather(consumer_task, return_exceptions=True)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Пытаюсь отловить инициированную ошибку TypeError, но скрипт продолжает висеть и не могу понять где именно тонкое место.
Приходится обращаться к коллективному разуму.

Comment: Во-первых, вы забыли await перед queue.put. Во-вторых, висит на `await queue.join()` потому что consumer завершает работу из-за TypeError и забирать объекты из непустой очереди больше некому

Comment: В python 3.11 появился асинхронный менеджер контекста и с группой задач `async with asyncio.TaskGroup()` эта проблема решается за вас. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780600/how-to-raise-exceptions-in-python-asyncio-background-task/75783528#75783528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обработать ошибку `TypeError` и продолжить исполнение, вы должны:

1. Поместить обработку внутрь цикла `while`
2. Убрать строчку `raise e`

Также может возникать ошибка, связанная с тем, что вы не применяете оператор `await` к вызову корутины `queue.put(None)` в блоке "Запуск продюсера". Вот исправленная версия кода:

```py
import asyncio


async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(7):
        await queue.put(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('Producer Queue size:', queue.qsize())


async def consumer(queue):
        while True:
            try:
                item = await queue.get()
                await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
                print(item)

                if item is None:
                    print('Queue is empty')
                    queue.task_done()
                    break

                if item == 3:
                    raise TypeError("Producer got exception")

                queue.task_done()
                print('Queue size:', queue.qsize())

            except TypeError as e:
                print(f'Error happened asf {e}')
                queue.task_done()

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    # Запуск продюсера
    await asyncio.gather(producer_task)
    await queue.put(None)
    # .join чтобы работало пока очередь непуста
    await queue.join()
    consumer_task.cancel()  # Выход из цикла while
    # Запуск consumer_task с возвратом ошибок
    result = await asyncio.gather(consumer_task, return_exceptions=True)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Как упомянул @andreymal, чтобы прервать исполнение, вы должны убрать строчку `await queue.join()` в функции `main` и вкрнуть строчку `raise e`:

```py
import asyncio


async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(7):
        await queue.put(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('Producer Queue size:', queue.qsize())


async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            item = await queue.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            print(item)

            if item is None:
                print('Queue is empty')
                queue.task_done()
                break

            if item == 3:
                raise TypeError("Producer got exception")

            queue.task_done()
            print('Queue size:', queue.qsize())

        except TypeError as e:
            print(f'Error happened asf {e}')
            queue.task_done()
            raise e


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    # Запуск продюсера
    await asyncio.gather(producer_task)

    await queue.put(None)
    # .join чтобы работало пока очередь непуста
    consumer_task.cancel()  # Выход из цикла while
    # Запуск consumer_task с возвратом ошибок
    result = await asyncio.gather(consumer_task, return_exceptions=True)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный, пожалуйста!)

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгий ответ.
Ошибку словить можно, но необходимо, чтобы все элементы находящиеся в очереди были обработаны, именно поэтому я использовал метод .join в функции .main(). В представленной реализации сразу же при возникновении ошибки оставшиеся элементы не обрабатываются, а падают после элемента равного 3.